# Diagonalizing a matrix

Tags: matrices

Assume I have matrix

${\bf H}=  \begin{bmatrix}
    {\bf H}_{11}       &   {\bf H}_{12}  \\
  {\bf H}_{21}       &   {\bf H}_{22}  
\end{bmatrix}$

where ${\bf H_{ij}}$ is a $Nr\times Nt$ matrix $i,j \in[1:2]$. Now assume I have another matrix

${\bf F}=  \begin{bmatrix}
    {\bf f}_{11}       &   {\bf 0}      \\
  {\bf 0}       &   {\bf f}_{22} 
\end{bmatrix}$

where vector ${\bf f}_{ij}$ is $Nt\times 1$ vector and same for  ${\bf 0}$ is $Nt \times 1$.

My goal is to find ${\bf f_{11}}$ and ${\bf f_{22}}$ that can can make the 
the product

$$ \arg\min_{f_{11},f_{22}} ||{\bf H} {\bf F} - \begin{bmatrix}
    {\bf H}_{11}{\bf f}_{11}       &   {\bf 0}      \\
  {\bf 0}       &      {\bf H}_{22}{\bf f}_{22}
\end{bmatrix}||
$$

Is that possible?

Comment: which norm do you use?

Comment: if it is the frobenius norm, than it is just $\min \| H_{21} f_{11} \|^2 + \| H_{12} f_{22} \|^2$. And the set of minimizers is trivially $\ker H_{21} \times \ker H_{12}$.

Comment: frobenius would be best

Comment: thank you very much. can you put you answer in the answers below and provide me more details. very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

(I am lazy and won't write the matrices in bold.)

**Hints:**

1. $HF - \begin{bmatrix} H_{11} f_{11} & 0 \\ 0 & H_{22} f_{22} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & H_{12} f_{22} \\ H_{21} f_{11} & 0 \end{bmatrix}$
2. $ \left\|\begin{bmatrix} 0 & X \\ Y & 0 \end{bmatrix} \right\|_F^2 = \|X\|_F^2 + \|Y\|_F^2 $
3. $\min \| A x \| = 0$